# Make color of first option in selection form, and clickable font awesome

Tags: html, css, forms, font-awesome

Can you tell me how to the change color of first option in selection to grey? (Like above)

Also, how to make a clickable icon to show all options? Because it doesn’t work correctly.

```
<div class="form__group form__group-selection">
    <label for="location" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></label>
    <select name="location" id="location" class="form__select">
        <option class="form__select-option" value="selected" selected>Select one option</option>
        <option class="form__select-option" value="polska">Polska</option>
        <option class="form__select-option" value="lotwa">Łotwa </option>
        <option class="form__select-option" value="estonia">Estonia</option>
        <option class="form__select-option" value="anglia">Anglia</option>
        <option class="form__select-option" value="czopki">Czopki</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Link: https://codepen.io/direct96/pen/zJbpPZ - Codepen

Comment: you mean you want to disable the "Select one option" option ?

Comment: Yes, and make it color grey

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question in your question. Also, please include all relevant code *in the question on Stack Overflow*, not on an external site. You've included the HTML, which is great, but of course just HTML code would not show all options :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've update jsFiddle.
Notice that I've also changed the HTML part, because I think you want to use the "disabled" attribute (and because of that, you'll have to add the "selected" attribute also).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMe(sel)
    {
      sel.style.color = "#000";              
    }
</script>
```

```css
$header-text-color: #efefef;
$form-bgn-color: #f6f6f6;
$form-text-color: #c5c5c5;
$color-input-focus: #6ba81a;

@mixin inputFonts {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  background-color: $form-bgn-color;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

html {
  font-size: 65.2%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    #c5eff3 15%,
    #f59f4d 70%,
    #bc2029 100%
  );
}

.form {
  &__header {
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: $header-text-color;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px black;
  }
  &__box {
    background-color: $form-bgn-color;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: -1rem;
      right: -1rem;
      top: -1rem;
      bottom: -1rem;

      border: 1rem solid rgba(#000000, 0.2);
    }
  }

  &__group {
    border: $form-text-color 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    &-selection {
      &::before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f0d7";
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: $form-text-color;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 2%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
    }
  }
  &__label {
    i {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: $form-text-color;
      padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
      position: relative;

      &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15%;
        right: -1px;
        height: 75%;
        border-right: solid 1px $form-text-color;
      }
    }
  }
  &__input-text {
    width: 100%;
    @include inputFonts();

    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    &::placeholder {
      color: $form-text-color;
    }
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      border: $color-input-focus 2px solid;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }
  &__select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    @include inputFonts();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Forms</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form">
      <h1 class="form__header">
        Register Form
      </h1>

      <form action="" class="form__box">
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="username" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></label>
          <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="password" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></label>
          <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="password-repeat" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></label>
          <input type="password" id="password-repeat" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="email" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group form__group-selection" onchange="changeMe(this)">
          <label for="location" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></label>
          <select name="location" id="location" class="form__select">
            <option  selected disabled class="form__select-option" value="selected" selected>Select one option</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="polska">Polska</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="lotwa">Łotwa </option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="estonia">Estonia</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="anglia">Anglia</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="czopki">Czopki</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div style="height: 5000px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the "Select one option" look grey, you just have to add the "disabled" attribute to the option. I'm not sure about what you mean by "a clickable icon to show all options", but there's no "clean" way to do that, it could be done with some js, but i'm not sure it would work with all browsers.

```css
html {
  font-size: 65.2%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #c5eff3 15%, #f59f4d 70%, #bc2029 100%);
}

.form__header {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #efefef;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px black;
}
.form__box {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.form__box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  right: -1rem;
  top: -1rem;
  bottom: -1rem;
  border: 1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form__group {
  border: #c5c5c5 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.form__group:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.form__group-selection::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.form__label i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.form__label i::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: -1px;
  height: 75%;
  border-right: solid 1px #c5c5c5;
}
.form__input-text {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.form__input-text::placeholder {
  color: #c5c5c5;
}
.form__input-text:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: #6ba81a 2px solid;
  z-index: 1;
}
.form__select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Forms</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form">
      <h1 class="form__header">
        Register Form
      </h1>

      <form action="" class="form__box">
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="username" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></label>
          <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="password" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></label>
          <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="password-repeat" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></label>
          <input type="password" id="password-repeat" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <label for="email" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form__input-text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group form__group-selection">
          <label for="location" class="form__label"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></label>
          <select name="location" id="location" class="form__select">
            <option class="form__select-option" value="selected" selected disabled>Select one option</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="polska">Polska</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="lotwa">Łotwa </option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="estonia">Estonia</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="anglia">Anglia</option>
            <option class="form__select-option" value="czopki">Czopki</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div style="height: 5000px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```